# Como alterar nome da coluna de uma tabela usando o comando Add-Migration Code First Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, code-first

Tenho uma tabela já criada e quero trocar o nome da coluna sem que elas seja excluída, pois a mesma já tem muitas informações.

Fiz o procedimento de renomear a propriedade Rua para Endereço na classe e após executei o comando **Add-Migration Mudanca-de-Nome-Rua-para-Endereco** assim o Entity Framework gerou uma classe contendo a mudança que será realizada, mas vejo que irá acontecer um Drop na Coluna ao invés de Renomear.

Gostaria de saber qual o procedimento que devo fazer para realizar esta manutenção.

**Código abaixo**

```
public override void Up()
{
  AddColumn("dbo.Empresas", "Endereco", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100));
  DropColumn("dbo.Empresas", "Rua");
 }

 public override void Down()
 {
    AddColumn("dbo.Empresas", "Rua", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100));
    DropColumn("dbo.Empresas", "Endereco");
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere seu arquivo de configurações para isso:

```
public override void Up()
{
 RenameColumn("dbo.Empresas", "Rua", "Endereco");
 }

 public override void Down()
 {
   RenameColumn("dbo.Empresas", "Endereco", "Rua");
 }
```